# Circle through point of intersection of two circles.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Suppose we have two circles $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Why is the circle through the point of intersection of the two circles given by:

$S_1 + \lambda(S_2 - S_1) = 0$

and not:

$S_2 + \lambda(S_1) = 0$?

These two questions along with their solutions are the source of my confusion:

**Question 1)**

[image]

**Question 2)**
[image]

It can be clearly seen that in the first question then have used $S_1 + \lambda (S_2) = 0$

And in the next one $S_1 + \lambda (S_1 - S_2) = 0$

So I am unable to understand when to use which form.

Comment: Hint: For $\lambda=1$ the correct equation of the circle should be $S_2$, but it actually is $S_1+S_2$ with the incorrect interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you want to have a linear combination of the two equations that represents *all* of the circles (and the line, which you can think of here as a circle with infinite radius) that pass through the two intersection points. If you write this combination as $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$, though, there’s no value of $\lambda$ that will produce the second circle. That’s why one uses the *affine* (a.k.a. convex) combination $S_1+\lambda(S_2-S_1)$, which I prefer to write as $(1-\lambda)S_1+\lambda S_2$. If you set $\lambda=1$ in that expression, you get $S_2$. Compare this to a common parametric equation for the line through two points $P_1$ and $P_2$: $P_1+\lambda(P_2-P_1)$. The same principle is at work here.

Now, if you happen to know that $S_2$ can’t be a solution to your problem, then you can use $S_1+\lambda S_2$ instead, but if you can’t be sure of that, you need to use the other combination so that you don’t overlook potential solutions. It’s just as easy to use the more inclusive version, so you might as well use that all of the time. It’s also a good exercise to prove to yourself that the two expressions do produce equations for the same sets of circles, other than $S_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the second question would $S_1 + \lambda S_2$ work? because we can be sure that $S_2$ cant be the solution to our problem.

Comment: Yes, if you’re sure that $S_2$ can’t be a solution. I’d use $(1-\lambda)S_1+\lambda S_2$ for both problems to avoid having to deal with rational functions of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the coefficients of each circle need to add up to 1 to make it a convex combination -- in the proposed example, they are $1-\lambda$ and $\lambda$ (for $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively). Having a convex combination ensures that if $p \in S_1 \cap S_2$ then $p$ will also be in the resulting figure.

In your suggestion, they are $\lambda$ and $1$...

Comment: what is a convex combination?

Comment: @Abcd if $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are some elements of the universe $U$, then a *convex combination* of them is $a_1x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \ldots + a_nx_n$ with $\sum_k a_k  = 1$. Without the last constraint, it is a *linear combination*.

Comment: But I saw a question where they have used $S_1 + \lambda S_2$ for equation of circle passing through intersection point

Comment: please see my edit.